# how to use pyspark min max function on a column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, max, min

I have a dataframe and i need to compare the value of a column.
The value of the column should be greater than 2 but less than 6
How should i achieve that

```
df.withColumn('coln',(min(max(df["cola"],2),6)))
```

This doesn't work

Comment: you want [`least`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.least) and [`greatest`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.greatest) not `min` and `max`

Comment: It throws me an error: TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 1 of type <class 'int'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function When I use least and greatest

Comment: `df.withColumn('coln',(least(greatest(df["cola"],lit(2)),lit(6))))` (where `least`, `greatest` and `lit` come from `pyspark.sql.functions`)

Comment: Thanks a ton....it worked